# sql query optimization sugarcrm

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am trying to optimize sql query in mysql db. Tried various variations with indexes, but nothing helps. Maybe I am missing something

Query:

```
SELECT  count(1) AS fAccounts
    from  sugarcrm.accounts t4, 
      ( SELECT  t3.related_id
            FROM  sugarcrm.prospect_lists_prospects t3, sugarcrm.prospect_list_campaigns t2
            where  t3.deleted=0
              and  t3.related_type='Accounts'
              and  t3.prospect_list_id=t2.prospect_list_id
              and  t2.deleted=0
              and  t2.campaign_id='10909eb7-8080-45b6-8c9f-563b42be91e5'
      ) t3
    where  t4.deleted=0
      and  t4.id=t3.related_id;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type |   table    |  type  |                   possible_keys                   |      key       | key_len |             ref              |  rows  |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                                              | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                         |   5000 |             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t4         | eq_ref | PRIMARY;idx_accnt_id_del;idx_accnt_assigned_del   | PRIMARY        | 108     | t3.related_id                |      1 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t2         | ref    | idx_pro_id;idx_cam_id;idx_prospect_list_campaigns | idx_cam_id     | 111     |                              |      1 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t3         | ref    | idx_plp_pro_id;idx_plp_rel_id_2                   | idx_plp_pro_id | 111     | sugarcrm.t2.prospect_list_id | 463968 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: why where clause twice??? Its not allowed

Comment: @SmitaAhinave it's between parenthesis, it's a sub-select.

Comment: Please use the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner query is the trouble maker.  There are two ways it could be performed:  Start with `t2` and do a "Nested Loop Join" to `t3` or vice versa.  The Optimizer will look at the `WHERE` clause and the table sizes and the indexes to estimate which one would be best to start with.  Let's give the optimizer the 'best' index for going each way:

Starting with t2:

```
t2:  INDEX(deleted, campaign_id) -- in either order
t3:  INDEX(prospect_list_id, deleted, related_type) -- in any order
```

Starting with t3:

```
t3:  INDEX(deleted, related_type) -- in either order
t2:  INDEX(prospect_list_id, deleted, campaign_id) -- in any order
```

Rather than adding 2 indexes to each table, let's do

```
t2:  INDEX(campaign_id, deleted, prospect_list_id)  -- in this order
t3:  INDEX(related_type, deleted, prospect_list_id)  -- in this order
```

Similarly, t4 (which will be last) needs

```
INDEX(deleted, id)
```

unless it is InnoDB and already has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, which will be 'clustered' with the data.

There is a problem...  When you do a `JOIN`, then compute aggregates, the `JOIN` first gives you an explosion of rows, then the `COUNT()` counts too many of them, thereby getting an inflated number.  So, be sure to sanity check the results.

Since the only need for t4 is to verify that the `related_id` is there, the query could be reformulated as

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS fAccounts
    FROM  prospect_lists_prospects t3
    -- Note the use of `JOIN...ON...`:
    JOIN  prospect_list_campaigns t2 ON t3.prospect_list_id=t2.prospect_list_id
    where  t3.deleted=0
      and  t3.related_type='Accounts'
      and  t2.deleted=0
      and  t2.campaign_id='10909eb7-8080-45b6-8c9f-563b42be91e5'
      AND  ( EXISTS *
            FROM  accounts
            FROM  accounts t4
            WHERE  t4.id = t3.related_id 
           )
```

This still needs the suggested indexes (one per table).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use `DISTINCT` anywhere, I see no need to bother creating a temporary table. Try this one:

```
SELECT 
     count(1) AS fAccounts
  from sugarcrm.accounts t4 inner join
       sugarcrm.prospect_lists_prospects t3 on t4.id=t3.related_id inner join
       sugarcrm.prospect_list_campaigns t2 on t3.prospect_list_id=t2.prospect_list_id
  where t3.deleted=0 
    and t3.related_type='Accounts' 
    and t2.deleted=0 
    and t2.campaign_id='10909eb7-8080-45b6-8c9f-563b42be91e5'
    and t4.deleted=0
```

Comment: Tried yours example, bus query duration increased dramatically: from 3-4sec (my example) to more than 2mins (yours example with added indexes on inner join)..

Comment: I'm sorry about the outcome. I didn't actually take in account the total number of rows in each table.